# Converting "simple" timezone offset (-7) to "full" offset (-07:00)

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

Okay, so I've been trying to figure this out on and off for two weeks now, and I am pretty close but I just need that last push. I'm working with an API that returns a bunch of events, all in different timezones. The API simply gives me offsets of `-5`, `-7`, etc... I am using moment.js to parse times and timezones, which will then return events in the user's timezone and it only accepts a "full" timezone string such as `-07:00`. So I started to manipulate the data in JS with the following:

```
// number padding
  function pad(n) { 
      if (n < 10 & n >=0){
        return ("0" + n);
      } 
      if(n < 0 & n > -11){
        return ("-0" + Math.abs(n));
      }
      return n; 
    }

  var timedate = '2017/03/02 1:05',
      ampm = 'PM',
      zone = '-5',
      padded = pad(zone),
      adjustedZone = parseInt(padded).toFixed(2),
      adjustedTwo = adjustedZone.replace('.', ':');
```

This is very very close, with the exception that `.toFixed` strips my leading zero and simply returns `-5:00`.

How can I preserve leading zeros in this scenario? I also need to support the `-10:00` timezone as well, and potentially any positive timezones, although my target user would be North American, but would be a GIANT plus to support all timezones.

Any help is much appreciated, you can also see a very messy codepen [here](http://codepen.io/erwstout/pen/JWGJzN?editors=1010).

Comment: Not all offsets are whole hours, how does it represent half hours like +05:30 or quarter hours like -08:45 or +05:45 (those are [*actual offsets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets))?

Comment: @RobG thats a valid concern, I'm not actually sure at the moment. Hopefully moment.js will handle that.

Comment: You're trying to parse the time zone offset comes from the source to a format that is acceptable to moment.js. Without knowing the source format, it's difficult to recommend how to parse and reformat it. Moment.js will accept ­­±HH:MM or ±HHMM, so you need to know how to reformat the minutes part too. E.g. is -08:45 represented as "-8:45" or "-8.75" or …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: -9 not -11 in padding, see code below &
You are very close, just "pad the minutes of time for desired output" (see output below) :

```js
// number padding
  function pad(n) { 
      if (n < 10 & n >=0){
        return ("0" + n);
      }
      // NOTE: -9 not -11
      if(n < 0 & n >= -9){
        return ("-0" + Math.abs(n));
      }
      return n; 
    }

  var timedate = '2017/03/02 1:05',
      ampm = 'PM',
      zone = '-5',
      //padded = pad(zone),
      adjustedZone = parseInt(zone).toFixed(2),
      adjustedTwo = adjustedZone.replace('.', ':');
      
  //console.log(padded);
  console.log('adjustedZone: ' + adjustedZone);
  console.log('adjustedTwo:  ' + adjustedTwo);
  
  // pad the minutes of time for desired output
  var a = adjustedTwo.split(':');
  var output = pad(a[0]) + ':' + a[1];
  console.log('final output: ' + output);
  
  zone = '-10';
  a = parseInt(zone).toFixed(2).split('.');
  output = pad(a[0]) + ':' + a[1];
  console.log('final output (for zone = ' + zone + '): ' + output);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Andre, I got so caught up with the leading zeros I didn't think to do that. Appreciate your help getting me to the finish line. Cheers!

Comment: Please note the >= -9 (or > -10 if you prefer), & its a pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

why you can't use `utcOffset` from moment JS

```
moment(dateValue).utcOffset(-7);
```

Comment: Users will be able to set timezones to whatever zone they wish, so I need to add timezone support, not just offset to local time.

Comment: so for that you can set timezone as well using moment(dateValue).utcOffset(-7).tz('timezone');

Comment: Cool, I'll test it out. It definately would be more efficient. I've got it all working now, but less code would always be nice.

Comment: sure do let me know